# Using OR condition in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have three columns of data - a sum column (`A`) and then the two columns that form the sum (`B` and `C`). Sometimes, just one of the `B` and `C` columns is filled in; occasionally the `B` and `C` columns are both blank.

I want to SUM column `A` (i.e., a total of the totals), *only* when there is data in columns `B` and/or `C`. So, I'd hoped that the following would work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((B2:B10<>"")+(C2:C20<>"")),A2:A10)
```

But the problem is, if there is data in BOTH columns B and C the array formed from `(B2:B10<>"")+(C2:C10<>"")` will sum to 2, and the preceding `--` doesn't convert it to a `TRUE` (e.g., `{1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0} + {1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1} = {2,1,1,2,0,2,2,1,1}`) and that final array is then multiplied with the values in column `A`, thus doubling values 1, 4, 6 and 7.

This seems like odd behaviour! How do I make it behave properly?!

Comment: So, let me get this straight: `A` is the sum of `B` and `C`, and you want to sum the values in `A` where `B` or (inclusive) `C` is not blank. What is the value of `A` when `B` and `C` are both blank? Is it not 0? If that's true, you should need no condition to sum the values in `A`.

Comment: Sadly not -- this is messy data that's been completed through an online survey. Columns B and C are female/male split. So they might know that 10 people were counted, but not know the gender divide. But if I sum column A and then start doing sums with that total, it'll skew things.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$11*($B$2:$B$11&$C$2:$C$11<>""))
```

The idea is that the concatenation of `B` and `C` is blank only if both are blank.

Answer (score 1):

Aha - I needed the `SIGN` function:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10,SIGN((B2:B10<>"")+(C2:C10<>"")))`

I still find it weird that, as far as SUMPRODUCT is concerned, TRUE + TRUE = 2. And that 2 doesn't just evaluate to TRUE when `--` is in play.

Comment: The `--` is used to convert the Boolean value to a numeric value. Think of it as `TRUE*(-1)*(-1)`. The reason for this being done is that `SUMPRODUCT` only works on *numerical* arrays.

Comment: Look at the statement as it was written `--((B2:B10<>"")+(C2:C10<>""))`. To me, this should convert to Boolean as its last step; i.e., even if it sees a '2', it should just interpret this as `TRUE`. And `TRUE*(-1)*(-1)` just equals `TRUE`, not 2!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may consider `=SUMIFS()` function instead.

Your condition can be rewritten as:

- Condition 1: Column B is filled in and Column C is blank; OR
- Condition 2: Column B is blank and Column C is filled in; OR
- Condition 3: Column B and Column C are both filled in.

Since the 3 conditions are mutually exclusive, the complicated `SUMPRODUCT` is essentially `=SUMIF(Condition 1)+SUMIF(Condition 2)+SUMIF(Condition 3)`.  Rewritten as `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A10,B2:B10,"<>",C2:C10,"")+SUMIFS(A2:A10,B2:B10,"",C2:C10,"<>")+SUMIFS(A2:A10,B2:B10,"<>",C2:C10,"<>")
```

Performance-wise, this solution may be better than using `SUMPRODUCT` as well if there is a large number of rows to summarise.